# Почему в функции послать сообщение, сообщение в БД записываються крокозябликами?

Tags: sql, кодировка, php, javascript

Почему в функции послать сообщение, сообщение в БД записываются крокозябликами (РќСѓР¶РЅРѕ Р±СѓРґРµС‚ Р·Р°РјРµРЅРёС‚СЊ РєРѕРІСЂРёРєРё РЅР° Р±РѕР»РµРµ СЃС‚РёР»СЊРЅС‹Рµ Рё РєСЂР°СЃРёРІС‹Рµ.)

Таблица t_carlog
Поле message     тип text сравнение cp1251_general_ci

```
    php     function saveMessage(){
            // Security fix. Changed from:
                // car_id = '".$_REQUEST['car_id']."',
            // to:
                // car_id = '".TUsers::getCurrentCar()."',
            $sql = "INSERT INTO 
                        ".$this->defaultTable."
                    SET
                        car_id = '".TUsers::getCurrentCar()."',
                        action_id = '8',
                        message = '".$this->pr2($_REQUEST['msg'])."',
                        date = '".$this->myDate(_DATE_FORMAT_SQL_FULL)."'
                    ";
            $res = $this->dataBase->execQuery($sql);
            // Новая запись в журнале
            TSpecial::setLog(19, '', NULL, 8);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: > записываються крокозябликами

my god 

> Что в коде JS нужно изменить?

скорее всего, ничего - проблема, вероятнее всего, в несоответствии кодировок подключения к БД, таблицы в БД и скрипте-обработчике.

Comment: Но подключение у меня происходит в кодировке cp1251. Сообщения из других форм в другие таблицы записываются нормально... А здесь почему-то облом непойму?

Показал функцию...

Comment: @Volt хорошая блоксхемка да жаль ссыль на оригинал полетела :(

Comment: @MDJHD, пожалуйста: http://pics.nyamo.org/77eddd73b9961ce0058385dc89cdc588.png

Comment: Помогите разобраться. Печатаю текст -> Сохранить -> Текст сразу добавляется в нормальном виде на форму. И улетает в БД. В базе появляеться в виде иероглифов. Естественно перезагружаю форму, и иероглифы появляються и на форме... В чем причина?

Comment: Причина в cp2151, если надо именно в этой кодировке - перекодируйте в скрипте перед отправкой в ДБ, если не хочется заморачиваться с перекодировками - переводите ввесь сайт (c БД) на utf8, как и рекомендует @Volt и будете довольны!

Answer (score 1):

Для детектирования проблемы можно использовать [определитель корокозябликов.](http://pics.nyamo.org/77eddd73b9961ce0058385dc89cdc588.png)

Xmlhttprequest, на котором основан ajax работает при передаче с utf-8. Сервер же пытается распознать то что ему прислали согласно настройкам, в данном случае как cp-1251.

Цитата из [http://xmlhttprequest.ru/:](http://xmlhttprequest.ru/)

---

Все идущие на сервер параметры GET/POST, кроме случая multipart/form-data, кодируются в UTF-8. Не в кодировке страницы, а именно в UTF-8. Поэтому, например, в PHP их нужно при необходимости перекодировать функцией iconv.

```
// ajax.php
$name = iconv('UTF8','CP1251',$_GET['name']);
```

С другой стороны, ответ с сервера браузер воспринимает именно в той кодировке, которая указана в заголовке ответа Content-Type. Т.е, опять же, в PHP, чтобы браузер воспринял ответ в windows-1251 и нормально отобразил данные на странице в windows-1251, нужно послать заголовок с кодировкой в php-коде, например так:

```
// ajax.php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251');
```

Или же, такой заголовок должен добавить сервер. Например, в apache автоматически добавляется кодировка опцией:

в конфиге апача
    AddDefaultCharset windows-1251

---

Также можно прочитать [эту статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/17640/)

Самым идеологически верным решением является использовать utf-8 везде. cp-1251 - анахронизм.

Comment: Volt функции GET/POST у меня на сайте работают нормально. Данные записываются и извлекаются - прекрасно. Загвоздка именно в этой функции с применением JS. Только в этой формочке. Почему?
Применительно к скрипту JS(он записан в .html файле) как правильно записать отправку с перекодировкой?

Comment: @Serg107, а в какой кодировке сам файл со скриптом?

Comment: html файл где прописан JS 1251-ANSI кириллица

Comment: Применил конвертацию при отправке на сервер как советовал Volt 
iconv. Помогло! Спасибо всем... 
Еще не работает поиск задавал вопрос  http://hashcode.ru/questions/309634/php-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-url-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5
Кто может прошу помочь...